# playing udp stream in html video object

Tags: html, udp, video-streaming

According to this page -

http://docs.brightsign.biz/display/DOC/HTML5+Video

you should be able to play a video stream in html just like this right ?

```
<video src="udp://239.192.1.1:5004" brightsign-properties="StreamTimeout:0;StreamLowLatency:0;">
```

i have built my html page, and when I inspect it, I have this in my body -

```
<div id="rightPane" style="position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 50%; width: 50%; height: 80%; background-color: green; visibility: visible;">
    <video src="udp://224.0.0.1:9999" brightsign-properties="StreamTimeout:0;StreamLowLatency:0;" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </video>
</div>
```

however when my page loads I get the error ,

```
GET udp://224.0.0.1:9999 net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

any idea on why it says unknown url scheme? is that page wrong in how I have to specify the udp url or?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

The  tag implementation is browser specific. I doubt you'll find much more than HTTP. I think FireFox supports RTSP.

I'd be surprised if you find wide browser support outside of HTTP.